# java ClassNotFoundException thrown during deserialization of Generics following refactoring

Tags: java, generics, refactoring, deserialization

I refactored (moved) a bunch of classes and now I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException` while trying to deserialize the Session. Classic.

I created a custome deserializer `SessionDeserializer extends ObjectInputStream` which works fine for most classes except for a Generic class `Result<T>`.

The generic class in itself hasn't moved, so I am guessing that the issue lies with the `T` object class which has been moved.

Now the issue is that the stacktrace doesn't specify the `T` class:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysite.shared.beans.Result
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
...
```

Do you know a way to work around this problem: either by finding which `T` class is contained inside the `Result<T>` object and adjusting the `SessionDeserializer`, or by skipping the deserialization of the `Result<T>` object alltogether?

EDIT

Added the result class below:

```
public class Result<T> implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
protected T t=null;
protected boolean success=false;
protected Map<String,String> errors=new HashMap<String,String>();
protected String message=null;

public void setData(T t){
    this.t=t;
}

public T getData(){
    return t;
}

public boolean isSuccess(){
    return success;
}

public Map<String,String> getErrors(){
    return errors;
}

public void setSuccess(boolean success){
    this.success=success;
}

public void setErrors(Map<String,String> errors){
    this.errors=errors;
}

protected void addError(String field, String msg){
    errors.put(field,msg);
}

public String getMessage(){
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message){
    this.message=message;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the issue is that the stacktrace doesn't specify the T class.

That's because it is not the `T` class that is the problem here.  The problem is the `Result` class.  Trust the exception message.

I can't tell you why the classloader cannot find your `Result` class, but possible explanations are:

- the `Result` class is not on your webapps classloader's classpath, or
- this class depends on some other class that is missing, or
- this class has an initialization dependency on some other class whose initialization has failed.

Comment: The thing is the Result class hasn't changed nor moved since 2014 and I only started seing this error recently.

Comment: I think it is the initialization of the T inside the result class that fails (I've added the result class to the question)

Comment: No ... I mean some >>class<< initialization; i.e. the initialization of the classes static variables and execution of its static blocks.  If these throw an unchecked exception, a class is marked as having failed.  If this has happened you should see other stacktraces reporting the original problem

Comment: *"The thing is the Result class hasn't changed nor moved since 2014 and I only started seing this error recently."* - Well, it doesn't have to have changed to be the cause of the problem.  It might just be missing at runtime ... 'cos it is >>now<< in a JAR file that isn't on the runtime classpath.

Comment: You're right the class was missing on the classpath of one of the modules. Thanks for your help